# Visual Studio Code: Open file clicking on path

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

in Visual Studio Code, how can I open a linked file by CTRL+Click on it for example like it works in Netbeans:

```
include_once("./auth.php");
require './Class.php';
```

, ?

Comment: It doesn't work for include_once

Answer (score 3):

you can use the extension I wrote [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) (historical name) to define and construct DocumentLinks (ctrl-clickable)

You have to define a "rule" for PHP files in your `settings.json`

```json
  "html-related-links.include": {
    "php": [
      "(?:require|include)(?:_once)?\\('([^']+)'\\)",
      "(?:require|include)(?:_once)? '([^']+)'",
      "(?:require|include)(?:_once)?\\(\"([^\"]+)\"\\)",
      "(?:require|include)(?:_once)? \"([^\"]+)\""
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Kindly reminder that there's also `include`, `require` and `require_once`, and of course the parenthesis are optional, you can have white spaces, single quoted strings... (I'm not saying this is wrong, just that it needs extra work to make it a general solution for people coming here via Google).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you can add multiple objects in the array to cover all cases, you don't need to try to cram it all in 1 regex

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you can try the update