# Link to click on another file/folder on VSCode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to create links on VSCode to (for example) access file 2 from file 1?

For example:

```
If you wish to see more info about x then see here: [link/path/to/file/2]
```

That way, I can allow myself (and others) to easily access a file within a particular folder.

Thanks

Comment: have a  look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77410137/9938317

Comment: I think it might do! Strange it never popped up as an option. Thank you!